# Is the Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomology the only interesting cohomology for Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

When talking about the cohomology space of a Lie algebras, it comes naturally to refer to the Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomology, is there other interesting type of cohomology for Lie algebra?

Comment: Just via a few Wikipedia clicks I got to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Fuks_cohomology

Comment: If we think of this cohomology as right derived functors of the fixed-vector functor, aren't these "named" cohomologies just computations by differing resolutions, which we know (modulo technicalities) must produce "the same" outcome? A more elementary case is finite-group cohomology, where homology and cohomology are often pseudo-elementarily "defined" in terms of specific resolutions... but can be understood more instrinsically as derived functors.

Comment: @paulgarrett Maybe the question is about cohomologies just not isomorphic to those derived functors? I am not aware, for example, of the universal determination of the Gelfand-Fuks cohomology via derived functors. Kapranov seems to be relating it to factorization algebra formalism, but I don't know the details or whether this gives some derived functor definition.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, you may well be correct! I'm insufficiently expert...

Comment: Well there's ofc CE cohom with coeffs in natural g-modules, eg Ug^{ad} will produce Hochschild cohom of Ug. If u have a topology u could take continuous cochains as in GK but this seems a bit cheap. If u have a Killing form u could take cohom of the centrally extended loop algebra, or say vertex algebra cohom of the associated VOA. All of these make sense with coefficients in modules and I'm sure there are countless other examples of greater or lesser naturality. It might be best to be a bit more precise wrt what u're looking for.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე the work of Kapranov is joint with  Ben Hennion. The factorization formalism is, afaik, used to reduce computations to local setting of Vir type algebras in higher dimensions. I don't think it gives a univ prop. In the Clausen Scholze work on condensed math the authors seem to claim to give der functor interps for continuous group cohom, and so I imagine their formalism works for Lie algebras too.

Comment: @EBz Very interesting! Seems like you are entitled to give an answer here :)

Comment: @EBz If I understand what you're suggesting correctly, those various cohomologies are all supposed to end up roughly being the Lie algebra cohomology of some closely related Lie algebra- so not super 'new'. (depending on your context, you might check out https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.01391.pdf or https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.5803.pdf)

Comment: also, depending on what you mean by 'cohomology theory', the answer 'there aren't really any other sorts of cohomology theories'. In general, if you have some category of algebraic gadgets, you can form the "tangent category" which classifies cohomology theories for that gadget. In the case of Lie algebras you end up with the category of representations of Lie algebras, and each such representation corresponds to the cohomology theory which is just "Lie algebra cohomology with coefficients in that representation". In characteristic zero, that's computed by the CE cpx, as you say

Comment: @dylan thanks for the comments, ur remarks about the tgt category construction are well taken! My point was more that at the level of gen of the current question there are ofc lots of ways to produce examples, in ur tgt cat formalism eg by composing with endofunctors of cat of Lie algebras, or by mapping to other cats and using same formalism (HH for Ug, Poisson cohom of Sg, Leibniz cohom as YCor suggests, etc.) certainly VOA cohom of loop lie alg is defined in a manner reminiscent of CE cohom, but I don't think it reduces to it in any obv sense afaik

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not the only one. For instance, Leibniz cohomology is interesting for Lie algebras themselves. See [this answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/a/262822/14094) for references.